# Mouse Trigger event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Datatable.

I want to select a custom checkbox in a table that selects the row.

But when I click on the checkbox, it is not selected yet (obviously) but I need to get the selected rows from the datatable. What event do I need to use to make this work?

mouseup doesn't up.

```
$('.select-checkbox').click(function () {
    var rowsStatus = table.rows('.selected').data();
    console.log(rowsStatus);
});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code to your question.

Comment: it's just a checkbox with class `select-checkbox` . When I click it will get the rows that have selected class from a table. but when i click, it's not selected yet.

Comment: In case of Data-tables use this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abhbs4x8/

Comment: I think it would be better to get all selected checkboxes onchange event, not onclick

Comment: @JamilAlisgenderov Why. Please give reasons. Some older browsers for example did not trigger change until focus was lost

Comment: @user9299353 "Custom checkbox" "Datatable" it s not "just a checkbox"

Comment: @mplungjan I see, what is the best way then?

Comment: See link in @SebastienD's answer